# Has my previous windows drive been erased?

Tags: 16.04, windows

Just today afternoon I installed ubuntu  and specifically remember selecting install alongside windows (7) option. However when later I checked out grub boot menu Windows 7 was not present there. I logged into ubuntu and to my very angry and sad astonishment i could see that there was no drive containing the Windows folder. Have I somehow by mistake uninstalled Windows out of my hard drive. Or it is somehow hidden in which case what can I do to access it ?

Comment: check with `gparted` to see what's on you HDD and sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Use gparted to look at the partitions on your hard drive to verify windows is still there, it should be if you installed it side by side. If you didn't do a full shutdown of windows, because of it's fast startup feature, then grub wouldn't have been able to mount the windows partition to see that it exists, and add it to the grub boot menu.

You will have to use a windows cd/usb and perform a boot repair. Make sure to do a full shutdown of windows, and then install the grub bootloader again or just reinstall ubuntu for simplicity and less steps but more time waiting.